# Examples and applications of homogeneus models in model theory.

Tags: model-theory, applications

Does anyone know any specific examples or applications of homogeneus models, to model theory or any other branch? For example, an application would be that prime models are isomorphic in a countable language and a complete theory (this may be found in Marker's Model Theory: An introduction)

---

The definition of homogeneus model can be found in:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Homogeneous_%28Model_Theory%29

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, anyway: I encountered this (and related notions) a lot with connection to geometric model theory and stability theory. It was important for notions like basis, dimension, rank, etc. See e.g. [Zilber's notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/zilber/est.pdf) on geometric stability theory.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. I was trying to find some specific examples to get intuition.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard a little bit about one of the uses of homogeneous structures:

I-There is a theory called the Theory of Relations or Relations Theory. That's about the study of order types like chains, total order, linear order. The theory of Relations written by Fraisse as a good reference was introduced to me. In chapter 12 of the book, the theory is connected to permutations and also about homogeneity is talked.
A relational structure is homogenous if it is countable and every isomorphism between finite structures extends to an automorphism."Countably infinite homogeneous structures " who are Fraisse limits of amalgamation classes of finite structures are very important objects. Seemingly these objects are connected to Permutation Group Theory, Combinatorics (For example, these go forward and are connected to Ramsey Theory).

II- If one considers to Topological Dynamics as a subset of Dynamical Systems, one of its aims is the study of minimal flows, universal minimal flows. For example, they want to compute the universal minimal flows of the group of automorphisms of a structure, the structure can be homogenous or -for example, $\omega$-homogenous- meanwhile it can be shaped the interaction between homogenous structures (the Model Theoretic aspect of the subject ) and Dynamical Systems.